# cost of PushNotification certificate

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hi I studied Push notification, and i find out I have to *Creating the SSL Certificate and Keys* and I do not know if it cost extra money because on website [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) it is not written if this service is for free(included in license) or is for extra money.I have bought business license for 99$.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to buy an SSL certificate from a 3rd party website like http://www.verisign.com/

Apple require that you have an SSL certificate to ensure that data sent through their service is being sent in a secure manner

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?Why?

Answer (score 1):

You must create certificates and key with the Apple developper portal : 
[Turorial here](http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/11/generate-apple-push-notification.html).